# Why would multiple animation queues be useful in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I understand how to use the fx queue, and specify other queues.  But what are some real scenarios where they would be useful?  I thought about fading out an animated scene on its own queue, but it's easier just to fade out the enclosing div without using a queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One scenario in which I use queues is when I'm fetching new data from my backend with ajax.
I call a function that fades out the div whose html I want to alter. Add in it;s queue a call to change its content to an ajax loader, and then fading it in again. On successful response, I do the same steps again in order to display the fetched html. Here's an example:

```
function searchGPS(position){
    $('#venueListDest').html('<img src="http://alpha.playdozer.com/static/loader.gif" style="margin: 15% auto 0;"/>').queue(function(nxt) {
        GET = "?lat=" + position.coords.latitude + "&long=" + position.coords.longitude;
        console.log(GET);
        nxt();
    }).queue(function(nxt) {
        window.location.href="#venues";
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/api/search/' + GET,
        data: {
            },
        success: function(data){
            $('#venueListDest').queue(function(nxt) {
                $(this).fadeOut();
                nxt();
            }).queue(function(nxt) {
                $(this).html(data);
                nxt();
            }).queue(function(nxt) {
                $(this).fadeIn();
                nxt();
            });
        }
        });             
        nxt();
    });
    }
```

If I don't use the queue(), I would end up with the html being changed before the element fading out.